# I want to call the next db if I press the button in the Django

Tags: python, django, templates, get

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Macro
# Create your views here.

def cmacroMacro(request):
    macro_data = Macro.objects.get(pk=1)
    context = {'macro_data':macro_data}
    return render(request, 'macro_pjt/registerMacro.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Macro(models.Model):
    tit = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pro = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pri = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    pro_i = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    re = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pro
```

html

```
    <body>
    <section>
        <div>b_id / b_pw</div>
        <textarea cols="30" id="b_id" placeholder="아이디"></textarea> <textarea cols="30" id="b_pw" placeholder="비밀번호"></textarea>

        <div>title</div>
        <textarea cols="70" id="title_1" placeholder="제목">{{ macro_data.tit }}</textarea>

        <div>product</div>
        <textarea cols="70" id="product" placeholder="상품명">{{ macro_data.pro }}</textarea>

        <div>price</div>
        <textarea cols="70" id="price" placeholder="상품가격">{{ macro_data.pri }}</textarea>

        <div>product_information</div>
        <textarea cols="70" id="product_information" placeholder="상품정보">{{ macro_data.pro_i }}</textarea>

        <div>review</div>
        <textarea cols="70" id="review" placeholder="상품평">{{ macro_data.re }}</textarea>

        <div>link</div>
        <textarea cols="70" id="link" placeholder="쿠팡링크">{{ macro_data.link }}</textarea>
    </section>
    <div>
        <div>img1</div>
        <div>img2</div>
        <div>img3</div>
    </div>
    <button>next page</button>
    </body>
```

The first row db is in textarea for each item.
If you press the next page button, I want to print out the second row db.
What should I do?
Thank you for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest would just be

```
def cmacroMacro(request):
    # get the pk to fetch from the url querystring ie `/site/macros?pk=3`
    macro_data = Macro.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get('pk',1))
    context = {'macro_data':macro_data}
    return render(request, 'macro_pjt/registerMacro.html', context)
```

then change your next button to

```
<a href="/view_item?pk={{ macro_dat.pk|add:"1" }}">Next</a>
     #   ^^^^^^^^^^  change this to your actual url...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
But when you do as you say,

Could not parse the remainder: ' + 1' from 'macro_data.pk + 1'

Comment: ahh thats right in django you have to use their math thing ... lemme see if i can find it i think its something like `{{ macro_dat.pk | add: "1" }}`  (yup https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add)

Comment: I'm the first person to start coding.
I'm really sorry, but let me ask you one last question.
The first row is well printed.
But when I clicked next,
Page not found (404)
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/views_item?pk=2
The error appears.

I think it's an error that comes from not registering urlpatterns.
I've been using urlpatterns that stretch from number one to more than 1,000.
How should I set it up?

I turned the translator to ask questions, and the context was weird.
I'm sorry for the rudeness.

Comment: just put the same as the page url anything after the ? doesnt really count as the URL but you didnt show what the url you were viewing was (you shouldnt need any new urls just use whatever url you were using to view the first one)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much.
All errors have been resolved.